# How to get values from one sub foreach and put this into parent loop and shuffle all values in array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I'm using WordPress and ACF Gallery. In each post I have a gallery with images.

I need to get all images from all galleries and shuffle they.

How I can achieve this?

Now I have this:

```
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            $images = get_field( 'gallery' );
            $size = 'full';
            if ( $images ) : ?>
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                    <img class="post-gallery" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <?php endforeach; ?>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <div class="post" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think we need to put somehow all posts and posts's galleries to one array and shuffle it?

**Update:**  js part(Infinite+masonry+imagesLoaded+randomize blocks

```
    var images = $('.container-post .col-50');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var imageFirst = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length -1) + 1;
    var imageSecond = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length -1) +1;
    images.eq(imageFirst).before(images.eq(imageSecond));
}
var $container = $('.container-post').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.container-post .col-50',
});

$container.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $container.masonry('layout');
});
var masonry = $container.data('masonry');

$container.infiniteScroll({
    outlayer: masonry,
    path: '.wp-pagenavi .page',
    append: '.container-post .col-50',
    scrollThread: 1,
    history: false,
    hideNav: '.wp-pagenavi',
    status: '.page-load-status',
});
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Have a nice day, all!

Comment: please add the javascript part as well, if any.

Comment: @NinaScholz Hi! question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally have PHP do the heavy lifting and, as you said, create a shuffled array that JS can loop over. For example:

```
<?php
    $collectedImages = [];
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $images = get_field('gallery');
            $size = 'full';
            if ($images === false) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $collectedImages[] = $image['url'];
            }
        }
    }
    shuffle($collectedImages);

    foreach ($collectedImages as $image) {
        // Render it! 
    }
?>
```

More info:

- [shuffle() - PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)